# How do I create my own template files in a sub-theme?

Tags: theming

Am new to Drupal so bear with me.

I am using Standford's Open Framework and have created a sub-theme based on it and activated it.  It works.  I can edit my sub-theme's `style.css` file and changes show up on my site.

However, when I create a `templates` directory and start adding my own templates to override the default ones, the changes are not showing up.

I copied, for example, the `page.tpl.php` file from the base theme's `templates` directory and modified it in my sub-theme. No changes appear.  If I make the same modifications on the base theme they do show up.

Here is my directory structure.  Am I missing something?  Do I have to specify something in my `.info` file?

```
`-- my-sub-theme
    |-- css
    |   `-- style.css
    |-- js
    |   `-- script.js
    |-- templates
    |   `-- page.tpl.php
    `-- my-sub-theme.info
```

Comment: If you're new to Drupal you might not have come across clearing the cache yet...after you add a template file or implement a hook, and in a few other situations, you need to clear Drupal's cache for the changes to show up. You can do this at /admin/config/development/performance, with [Drush](https://drupal.org/project/drush) or through a shortcut in the [admin menu](https://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) module

Comment: @clive That fixed it - bingo!  So it is caching the template hierarchy (that is, which files to read) but not the content of the files?  Thanks

Comment: Yep exactly, Drupal apps are pretty database (and in some case, file) heavy, so there's a lot of caching going on. If something doesn't work as you expect, clear the cache before trying anything else - it's a good rule to live by :)

Comment: @Clive - copy paste that as an answer because you got it first try! Thanks.